# Width of Browser minus 25%

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

So I have been trying to figure this out on my own for a little while. Figured I would ask here since I always seem to get some great responses.

So.  I want to know the dimensions of the browser window minus 25%.  I have a two column layout and i want to use tim thumb or regular attributes (just to test). to make sure that I get the correct height and width of the area I want to show on an image.

25% | rest of the page (this is where the image is).  the height I have no problem since I can do .height() - 240 (which I know because of my CSS. my question is the width.

Here is what I have so far, but cant seem to make it work.

```
var bg_width    = $(window).width() * .025;
var bg_height   = $(window).height() - 240;
$(".backgrounds img").each(function(bg_width,bg_height){
    $(this).attr('width',bg_width);
    $(this).attr('height',' + bg_height + ');
});
```

Anyone see anything wrong with this or why it doesnt work?

Comment: 0.025 isn't 25%. Should be 0.25

Comment: If you want the width - 25% then it should be `var bg_width = $(window).width() * 0.75;`

Answer (score 7):

.025 is not 25%

you want .25
you are off by a decimal

anyhow, that will give you 25%, but the width of the browser minus 25% is really 75%
so you REALLY want

```
myWidth = $(window).width() * .75
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `$(window).width()` is returning the correct width of the browser window, then

```
var bg_width    = $(window).width() * .025;
```

Isn't going to give you the the browser width - 25%:

> So. I want to know the dimensions of the browser window minus 25%

To do that you want:

```
var bg_width = $(window).width() * 0.75;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var bg_width    = $(window).width() * .75;
var bg_height   = $(window).height() - 240;
$(".backgrounds img").each(function(bg_width,bg_height){
    $(this).attr('width', bg_width);
    $(this).attr('height', bg_height);
});
```

note that for 75% it's **$(window).width() * .75;**

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it a typo:

```
$(this).attr('height',' + bg_height + ');
```

Should be:

```
$(this).attr('height', bg_height);
```